# Twitter typeahead only showing some items returned by bloodhound

Tags: twitter, twitter-typeahead

I'm using Bloodhound to fetch data from the database, then twitter typeahead to display the options below a search box.

Currently, the bloodhound part is finding the objects required, but the typeahead is not displaying them.

```
 var artist_retriever = new Bloodhound({
    // turns input query into string of tokens to send to database.
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

    remote: {
              // URL to fetch information from
              url: "/artists?query=%QUERY",
              wildcard: '%QUERY',
              // Manipulate the array of artists returned, for display to user.
              transform: function(array_of_artists){
                            // array of artists is returned from DB.
                            // Put each artist into a readable string
                            array_of_artists = create_artist_descriptions(array_of_artists)

                            console.log(array_of_artists)
                            // Returns correctly:
                            // [
                            //   { artist: "Joe" },
                            //   { artist: "Bob" },
                            //   { artist: "Smith" },
                            //   { artist: "Tom" },
                            // ]

                            return array_of_artists
                          }
            },

    // turns return value into a string of results, with this 'key' before each result.
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('artist'), 


  });

// display:



// instantiate the typeahead UI
  // https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md
  searcher = $('.typeahead').typeahead(
    // options:
    {
      hint: false
    },
    // datasets:
    {
      // Where to get data: User the bloodhound suggestion engine:
      source: artist_retriever.ttAdapter(),
      // Which attribute of each result from the database should be shown:
      displayKey: 'artist',
      templates: {
                    notFound: new_artist_option_template(),
                    footer: new_artist_option_template()
                 }
    }
  )
```

**Update**

It turns out that there's a weird bug in typeahead. It only seems to work with the "limit" attribute set to a maximum of 4. If you set "limit" to 5, the typeahead gives you nothing.

```
searcher = $('.typeahead').typeahead(
    // options:
    {
      hint: false
    },
    // datasets:
    {
      // Where to get data: User the bloodhound suggestion engine:
      source: artist_retriever.ttAdapter(),
      // Which attribute of each result from the database should be shown:
      displayKey: 'signature',
      limit: 4, // This can do a max of 4! Odd.
      templates: {
                    notFound: new_artist_option_template(),
                    footer: new_artist_option_template()
                 }
    }
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Currently working on something similar and finding typeahead to be a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: I just had the same problem and limiting results to 4 corrected it. Thanks BTW for that. However, did you file this bug in typeahead, or have some bug reference number that we can keep track of. Lastly, if you get time, and you do find out the reason for this problem, can you mention me in comments so that I get notified about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> This issue has been solved. Please see **update 2** directly.

I have reproduced this issue in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rash805115/kosocz84/).

As you said, its a bug. You also reported that this bug goes away if you do `limit:4`.

Actually on my end, or in the FIDDLE, I have experienced that this issue comes when the `number of results returned = value in limit`.

To test this issue in the FIDDLE, do the following:
Note: Searching for 1947 returns exactly 5 rows.

**When limit is set to 4:**
Searching for 1947 returns 4 results.

**When limit is set to 5:**
Searching for 1947 returns nothing.

**When limit is set to 6:**
Searching for 1947 returns one 1 result - the first result.

***Hence if you keep the limit set to 1 less than the actual number of results returned, then this will keep on working.***

I have also submitted this issue in their [github page](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1312). I will be keeping track of this issue and will keep updating this answer as need be.

## Update 1:

Found a [similar question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007825/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-hints-as-expected). **"Luciano García Bes"** seems to have figured the solution. Please direct all upvotes there.

Basically he says:

> It's counting the number of rendered hints before appending them, so
>   if the number of hints equals the limit it'll append an empty array.

To prevent this I just switched lines 1723 and 1724 so it looks like this:

```
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
rendered += suggestions.length;
```

## Update 2:

This issue has been fixed on pull [1212](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/1212). Closing our own issue [1312](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1312). The bug was corrected the same way discussed in `update 1`.