# Why typeahead.js is not showing all items in the ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use `typeahead.js` for showing ajax results in a form.
At first I tried with `Bloodhound` suggestion engine which comes with `typeahead` by default. But it wasn't showing all the items (i just shows 1 or sometimes two) returned by the server.

Following is the code I used;

```
 $('.autocomplete').livequery(function () {
            var input = this;
            $(input).removeClass('autocomplete');

            var _source = new Bloodhound({
                limit: 25,
                datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Text'),
                prefetch: $(input).attr('data-source'),
                remote: {
                    url: $(input).attr('data-source') + '?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY'
                }
            });

            _source.initialize();

            $(input).typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 0
            }, {
                displayKey: 'Text',
                source: _source,
                templates: {
                    notFound: 'No results found'
                }
            });

            $(input).on('typeahead:selected', function (evt, item) {
                $(input).parent().parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(item.Value);
            });
        })
```

Then I tried to do it without Bloodhound using following code without any change in results;

```
 $('.autocomplete').livequery(function () {
            var input = this;
            $(input).removeClass('autocomplete');

            $(input).typeahead({
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                limit: 50,
                minLength: 0
            }, {
                displayKey: 'Text',
                source: function (query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
                    $.get($(input).attr('data-source') + '?query=' + query, function (data) {
                        asyncResults(data);
                    });
                },
                templates: {
                    notFound: 'No results found'
                }
            });

            $(input).on('typeahead:selected', function (evt, item) {
                $(input).parent().parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').val(item.Value);
            });
        })
```

The response from the Server for the requests is as follows;

```
[
{
    "Text": "Marketing Executive",
    "Value": 1
},
{
    "Text": "CEO",
    "Value": 5
},
{
    "Text": "Manager",
    "Value": 6
},
{
    "Text": "Accountant",
    "Value": 7
}]
```

What is wrong with this? and how can I get typeahead to display all results returned by the Server?

Comment: by default only 5 suggestions will be shown , use `limit` options to increase it .  check [docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#options)

Comment: @JSantosh `limit: 50`, check the question.

Comment: you can't see 50 results right ?

Comment: @JSantosh I read somewhere that typeahead has some issues with showing all asyncresults when syncresults are fewer. Setting a higher limit was a workaround found on the internet.

Answer (score 8):

This is a bug in the control. This can be fixed by below  code change in `typeahead.bundle.js`

Switch lines 1723 and 1724 so it looks like this

```
that._append(query, suggestions.slice(0, that.limit - rendered));
rendered += suggestions.length;
```

Kudos for the post [Bootstrap Typeahead not showing hints as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007825/bootstrap-typeahead-not-showing-hints-as-expected)